# На странице обратной связи что-то не так

Tags: дефект

На странице [обратной связи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact) не работает поиск по справке. А при попытке отправить незаполненное сообщение без указания темы ничего не происходит. Если после этого задать что-то в поиске и нажать Enter, можно вовсе попасть на 404.

На других сайтах справка работает и при пустой отправке отображаются всплывающие информационные сообщения.